# UITableViewCell basic style on Storyboard can't select

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have strange behavior with `UITableView` on `Storyboard` today. I have created `UITableView` on `Storyboard`. After that I drag a `PrototyleCell` to this table and choose style is `Basic`. And I implement `DataSource` and `Delegate` on my `ViewController`. It show to simulator normal. But I can't tap to table for select a cell and `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` don't work too. In `Storyboard` I have checked `selectionStyle`. If I change style to another style, It work normally.

So my question is: this is a bug or it is a behavior of `UITableView`? And anyone can give some explanation for it.

Here is my code: [Problem Cell Code](https://github.com/vienvu89/ProblemBasiCell). I can't select when use it but when I set another style of cell on `storyboard` everything will ok.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No its neither bug nor normal behavior, you must be doing some basic mistake...

Try following code with tableview and prototype cell in storyboard, Everthing will work.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var dataSource = ["Ajay","Ajay","Ajay","Ajay","Ajay","Ajay"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell?

    if cell == nil {

        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    cell!.textLabel?.text   = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    return cell!

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   return dataSource.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print(indexPath.row)
}   }
```

Comment: No, I mention above I just change style and it work normally.

Comment: I just tried with 'basic' type cell, every this works perfectly, just cross check your code, delete cell in storybord and add it again,or clean your product and build again, there may be some minor mistake.

Comment: replace your cellForRowAtIndexPath with mine as I have posted above, it will work

Comment: You change style of cell So it is not I want in this question... I will know how to make cell select. I just want ask why this style can't select :|

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the
tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method. This is a required delegate you must implement.

Comment: Please read carefully. I have implemented datasource and delegate. Problem just with basic cell and when i change to other style it work normally